# How to use TntForm to replace TForm?

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

I am new to delphi 7, I installed TntControls into delphi7, and replace `TForm` to `TTntForm`, code like below:

```
uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
  Dialogs, StdCtrls, TntStdCtrls;

type
  TForm1 = class(TTntForm)
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;
```

But when I compile, the error throw:

```
Undeclared identifier: 'TTntForm'
```

Comment: `TntStdCtrls` is likely not the only unit you need to add to the `uses` clause. Is there a `TntForms` unit?

Comment: Like every time you see that error message you need to use the unit which declares that identifier.

Comment: Wouldn't you also need to edit the .dfm file also?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As people told you in comments, you have to add `TntForms` into the `uses` section. The  source code is publicly available on [GitHub](https://github.com/rofl0r/TntUnicode/blob/master/Source/TntForms.pas).

In case you still have the same error, be sure that the path to the `TntForms.pas` is added to `Tools > Environment Options > Library > Library Path` or at least under `Project > Options > Directories/Conditionals`.

Comment: A normal VCL project should not need the path to the .Tnt .Pas files, just the path to the corresponding DCUs.